# Setting alias to SQL Column based on results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to give a column an alias based on results for my game's ranking board. I am struggling to figure out where I should incorporate the line below into my query.

The desired result would be to have the G.Jobcode result rename itself to "Warrior" "Archer" "Mage" depending on the number result.

```
Select G.Jobcode as WARRIOR where G.Jobcode = 1;
```

```
USE DNWORLD

SELECT TOP 25 G.CharacterName, G.JobCode, G.PvPExp, D.PVPWin, D.PVPLose, D.PVPGiveUp
FROM PvPRanking as G
INNER JOIN PVPScores as D
ON G.CharacterID = D.CharacterID

ORDER BY  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalRank ASC )
```

Comment: How many job codes you have? Does jobcode 1 will have Warrior, Archer and Mage?

Comment: I probably have 90 job codes and each one will represent a different class in the game.

"Warrior" "Mage" etc..Yea i know its going to be a pretty fat query.

Comment: On the TOP 25 can be different jobcode, how should the code be decoded to a column-alias?
Sure you don't want to decode the value?

Comment: Errr I'm not particularly sure what you're saying, but essentially this is my issue.

For example, column result after running the query is = 1 then I want it to literally turn that value '1' to 'warrior' (visually)

Comment: Can't you create a table with your codes and names and join it in the query?

Comment: I'm using Datagrip, but sometimes I am forced to mess with Navicat SQL or SQL management studio

Comment: Datagrip isn't a DBMS - it's a SQL client that can connect to many different database products. But as you mention SSMS, you most certainly use Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry I got confused and thought you meant the application I use to do my work :(

Also thanks @Turo gunna give that a shot

Comment: I like the suggestion by @Turo above. I would either do that, or create an enum in my application to convert the int value into the string that I wanted. (Trying to dynamically rename a column in your query would cause result-set nightmares, I think.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that G.Jobcode is a numerical result, as mentioned by @Turo in the comments, creating a table with 2 columns would make it possible to join the result of the query above on G.Jobcode.

```
declare @ClassName Table (JobCode int, JobClass varchar(max))

insert into @ClassName (JobCode,JobClass) values
(1,'Warrior')
,(2,'Ranger')
,(3,'Mage')
[...]
```

Then join this table on the master table with ThisTable.JobCode = G.JobCode

```
USE DNWORLD

SELECT TOP 25 
 G.CharacterName
 ,G.JobCode
 ,T.JobClass
 ,G.PvPExp
 ,D.PVPWin
 ,D.PVPLose
 ,D.PVPGiveUp

FROM PvPRanking as G
INNER JOIN PVPScores as D ON G.CharacterID = D.CharacterID
LEFT JOIN @ClassName as T ON T.JobCode = G.JobCode

ORDER BY  RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TotalRank ASC )
```